# Ansible:Can not define var in Ad-hoc mode

Tags: ansible

I just want to define a var named 'a' with value 'b'
[image]

Comment: here is my hosts 
[rcp]
atom

Answer (score 2):

Works with `ansible 2.3.2.0`:

```
$ ansible test -m shell -a 'a="b"; echo $a'
test | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
b
```